# Use VBA to sum several cells above active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to use VBA to set a cell to sum several cells above the active cell. I have played around with some code that I came across but it is set to pull the entire column above the active cell. I do not understand the code enough to modify it to sum the cells two and three rows above. Here is what I have so far (only a portion of the macro posted):

```
Sub QRTLYdatagrab()

''''Script leading up to this point has been omitted''''

Range("U1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SUM('Asset_Dtl for CEQs for FAS 157'!J:J)"
Range("U1").End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0).Select

Dim r As Range, rAbove As Range
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set r = ActiveCell
Set rAbove = Range(r.Offset(-2, 0), Cells(2, r.Column))
r.Formula = "=SUM(" & rAbove.Address & ")"

''''Script after this point has been omitted''''

End Sub
```

A quick example: one quarter my data may utilize 402 rows. I have summed rows 1 - 402 in 403. 404 is pulling a sum from another tab. I need 406 to sum 403 and 404. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything and thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It would be easier to use excel formula

Comment: @phil652 I am certainly open to that.  How can I sum the cells 2 and three rows from my active cell? I would prefer to have this done in the code, the point of this is to automate this process so going in to manually do this would defeat that purpose. I tried using the 
   " ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1" code but couldn't get anything to come of it. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @pnuts Awesome! Thanks again for your help, pnuts. The only issue I am having is with my line:

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('Asset_Dtl for CEQs for FAS 157'!J:J)"


After the macro runs the cell is left with "=SUM('Asset_Dtl for CEQs for FAS 157'!J:(J))" and I have to manually go in to remove the parenthesis around the second J. Are you familiar with what causes this issue by chance?

Comment: @pnuts Aaah I see. I tried it without the R1C1 portion and it sort of works. It gives me the #REF error but when I go into the cell and hit enter it pulls the correct  data. I will continue to play around with that part.  Thanks so much for your assistance with this, it is greatly appreciated. Take care!

Comment: @pnuts Hey pnuts, I apologize for keeping this going but I do not see an option to select your response as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was provided by pnuts (site wont let me select his response as answer):

"Once you have selected the 406 cell

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-3]C:R[-2]C)"
```

–  pnuts yesterday"

Here is how I have applied it to my own macro:

```
Range("U1").End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-3]C)"
```

This allows the macro to go to the end of Column U (where I have established two sum cells) then select the cell three rows down. This cell will then sum the cells 4 and 3 rows above.